# Decode Java String in Command Line Tool

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding

I write a command line tool and the parameters of the string[] are already UTF-8 encoded.

sample: **java -jar myTool.jar -x "Gesch\u00E4ft"**

This string is now represented as "Gesch\u00E4ft" and I don't know how to decode it back. URIDecode/URLDecode/CharsetDecoder didn't work.

```
String test = args[2];
URI uri = null;
try {
    uri = URI.create(test);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Error:
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 5: Gesch\u00E4ft

Comment: `\u00E4` is not UTF-8, it is just a Java string literal for `ä`. `c3 a4` would be a hex-representation of the utf-8 encoding of `ä`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You `\uxxxx` is not URL format, it's Java format. You can use Properties.load which decodes these sequences

```
    String s1 = "Gesch\\u00E4ft";
    Properties props= new Properties();
    props.load(new StringReader(s1));
    String s2 = (String)props.keySet().iterator().next();
```